# How to force Hibernate to paginate over the same dataset it started the pagination with?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, insert, pagination

Let's say I have 5 elements in my `article` database table:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | bb   |
|  2 | cc   |
|  3 | dd   |
|  4 | ee   |
|  5 | ff   |
+----+------+
```

If I want to paginate my results with 2-element pages, I'll use the following query:

```java
Query query = session.createQuery("from Article order by name asc");
query.setFirstResult(pageNumber);
query.setMaxResults(2);
```

I read the first page:

```
1/bb
2/cc
```

Before I read the second page, another thread inserts a new element `6/aa` in the table (ordered by name):

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  6 | aa   |
|  1 | bb   |
|  2 | cc   |
|  3 | dd   |
|  4 | ee   |
|  5 | ff   |
+----+------+
```

If I read the second page, I'll have:

```
2/cc
3/dd
```

The `2/cc` element will then be read twice: duplicate.

Is there any way to force Hibernate to paginate over the same dataset it started the pagination with?

PS: such a scenario could also be found if the second thread executes an `update` query (e.g. changing the name of an element, thus the results of the sort), which I would like to avoid as well. Oh, and I'm not looking for a *if-already-read-then-remove-and-add-others-until-page-is-full* solution `;)`

Comment: if the updates changed the contents of the first page, then there is little gain in having a proper second page because the user did not see the updated first page.

Answer (score 1):

First solution I can see is to fetch ligthweight header records (id, title, etc) and store in user context. Then creating pagination based on that in-memory user context. Such context may be kept in http session for example.

Second solution is to remember timestamp when user starts with browsing/searching and append additional condition in HQL: where createdDate <= :timestamp.

Maybe this was be helpful.

Comment: While your first proposition won't suit my needs because of the large amount of records I actually have, the second one could be good a solution. It's quite strange Hibernate does not provide such a functionality natively though.